# Android create interface listener for onClick in Adapter

Tags: android

in my application i'm create simple interface to detect after click on adapter items into parent activity.after create interface and method into adapter i can not how to use this interface to call listener, for example:

Interface Class:

```
public interface IOnClickListListener {
    public void onClick(boolean click);
}
```

summurized Adapter:

```
private static class ViewHolder {
    public ViewHolder(View view) {
    }

    public void fill(final ArrayAdapter<SubjectListStructure> adapter, final SubjectListStructure item, final int position) {
        root.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                /* call interface to listen that */
            }
        });
    }
}

public void setOnClickListener(IOnClickOnNiyazmandihaListListener l){
    iOnClickOnNiyazmandihaListListener = l;
}
```

in this adapter after click on item, my interface must be call. now i want to listen that into activity by this code:

```
subjects_adapter.setOnClickListener(new IOnClickOnNiyazmandihaListListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(boolean click) {
                                Toast.makeText(G.currentActivity,"ddddd", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });
```

now how to call listener into adapter ?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to trigger/invoke the callback, simply call

```
boolean click = true
iOnClickOnNiyazmandihaListListener.onLogin(click)
```

from the adapter class

Answer (score 0):

In my honest opinion, if you intend to register the click event inside an adapter, you must pass the position of item which was clicked, instead of passing a boolean value to check if item was clicked or not. In this way, you will get a number of options to handle the clicked item callback.

Here is a simple implementation from my side according to your use-case.

1. Your interface class just require a small change as follows:

   `public interface IOnClickListListener {
   public void onClick(int positionOfItem);
   }`
2. Inside your adapter class, at the `onClick()` of your root's `setOnClickListener`, you must call the interface's method in the following way, considering `iOnClickOnNiyazmandihaListListener`  is a member variable of your adapter class

`iOnClickOnNiyazmandihaListListener.onClick(position)`

where `position` is passed as a parameter to `setOnClickListener` and it is the actual position of item clicked.

In this way, wherever you want this `onClick()` method to be called, you have to provide implementation of the interface in that class, about what you want to do with the clicked position when `onClick()` is triggered.

So whenever any list item is clicked, your custom implementation of the `onClick()` method will be used, and the code which you put inside that implemented method will be called.

**Example:**

Suppose you implemented this interface in an activity, then it tell you to override the onClick() method of your interface inside that activity, **i.e. to provide onClick() implementation**

So implementation of onClick() would look similar as follows:

`@Override
void onClick(int position){
//  do what you want to do with clicked item's position
Toast.makeText(this, "Item at position:" + position + " clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}`

For that, your class must have `implements IOnClickOnNiyazmandihaListListener` as its starting line.